# Script or SQL Query to export SQL Server tables to Excel 2010

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to extract data from around 5 databases to excel 2010. Each data base having around 300 tables. I want each tables to be 1 tables. So I will have around 300 sheets in one excel file. I will have 8 excel files.

I tried the query but ended up with error:

Query:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\ExcelExport\testing.xlsx;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
select * from dbo.GET
```

Error:

```
 OLE DB error trace [Non-interface error:  Provider not registered.].
 Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not locate registry entry for OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'.
```

Note: I refered this to get connection string; http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2010/

How can I reslove this?

Then,I tried this using improt export wizard. However, I'm getting below error.

```
Operation stopped...

 - Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)

 - Initializing Connections (Success)

- Setting SQL Command (Success)

 - Setting Source Connection (Success)

  - Setting Destination Connection (Success)

 - Validating (Success)

 - Prepare for Execute (Success)

 - Pre-execute (Error)
Messages
* Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE       DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc0202025: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: component "Destination - ACCOUNT" (145)      failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


  - Copying Rows (Warning)
Messages
* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


 - Post-execute (Stopped)
Messages
* Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - ACCOUNT" (145)" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 1 - ACCOUNTADDR" (426)" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 2 - ACCOUNTASSO" (547)" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 3 - ACCOUNTCON" (653)" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

* Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination 4 - ACCOUNTTYPE" (752)" wrote 0 rows.
```

I want to export all data at a time to one excel file very quickly.
How Can I slove this? Please help.

Comment: I have one question: What human can possibly make sense of 300 excel sheets of data? If this data is not for a human and is instead for upload into another system, use a format which is more appropriate such as native BCP or CSV. Excel will mess up your data dates and perform incorrect formatting.

Comment: @Nick, Thanks. But this is what client need. Also, CSV is also nice option, but CSV will not multiple sheet containing in one file.

Comment: Yes sometimes we need to do what the client wants eve when it makes no sense. With regards to your ACE.OLEDB, there are many many posts on this topic. You just need to install the ACE driver.

Comment: becareful with Excel and fields with leading zeros, as Excel will strip those off.  I would kindly suggest to the client that a better option is indeed CSV files, but zip each set of database files into one zip file, so you would end up with 5 zip files.